# When Deploy Google Web App from my Gmail account that own by company Account receive an error

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working on a Google Apps Script project that we need to deploy as web app but when I try to deploy a file (that own my an organization/different gSutie owner) from my Gmail account, I receive an error as below.

Please anyone that know how to change client domain settings so I can edit the script file in his account and can deploy and test myself.

Image[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to change/modify the permission of the domain in the [Google Admin Panel](http://admin.google.com/) in order for you to deploy a script on that domain.